# Python Popen to Compile Java

Tags: python, python-3.x, javac

I'm in the process of writing a little automarking script for a class I help teach. I've got it able to download the source code, write the java file, but for some reason I can't get the subprocess to actually compile the file. No errors are produced and it appears as if everything runs correctly but no class file is produced. Anyone shed some light on this for me? I don't use the subprocess module very much so I'm sure it is something simple I'm overlooking.

```
# compile main
proc = subprocess.Popen(['javac', 'Main.java'])
outs, errors = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
```

Everything is in the same directory and the environment path is set for javac to run without a path. I have also tried setting the cwd inside of the Popen command to no luck. Running under Admin rights command prompt in Windows but have also tried it on a Debian machine.

EDIT:
This code is also part of a for loop. If I remove it from the loop, it will compile but I do need to loop through many files here to grade in one go.

Comment: All I get is None from those. proc.wait() returns 0

Comment: oh sure, since you're not redirecting output & error. Can you try to change the file name to a non-existing one just to see what happens? also check `where javac`

Comment: proc = subprocess.Popen(['javac', 'Main.java'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    outs, errors = proc.communicate(timeout=15)    All i get in both outputs is b''

Comment: try `proc = subprocess.Popen(['javac', 'InexistentMain.java'])`

Comment: Just to make sure - you've tested trying to use `javac Main.java` manually from your command prompt, in the same cwd the program would be using it from, right? I tried running this on my machine and couldn't replicate the problem.

Comment: I get that javac cannot find the file. This is why I'm very confused. Its running the command but I'm not getting the output. If I run javac from the command line myself, it compiles. Just not from the script. I can manually compile. but the script returns no errors but won't compile and returns no errors if I used the same commands

Comment: Little more details here. I have the compile code in a loop, since I'm going through multiple files to test. If I just remove the loop, no issues and it works. As soon as I put the loop back around it, no go.